# Configure Burp to pass dynamic authentication token from the past response to the next request in intruder

Tags: authentication, web-application, penetration-test, session-management, burp-suite

I would like to reuse an authentication token (which is dynamic) between a response and a request in Burp Suite intruder.

By dynamic I mean that the token is invalidated after being sent to the server and that we get a new token in the response.

Here is what is happening:
[image: uml-ish_schematic]
Please note that in the request the token is in the body and that in the response it's a custom header (Token: x)

Comment: Not sure of a way directly, but there is a Python Scripter app in the BApp Store that you could use. It processes python scripts for each request and response. You might be able to do it that way.